# Show that $\lim_{t\to \infty} 1/t \; \max_{n \leq t} S_n \to E[X]$ a.s

Tags: limits

This is a twist on the strong law of large numbers.

$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ where $X_k$ are i.i.d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing stochastic here: to wit, assume that a real valued sequence $(s_n)$ is such that $s_n/n$ converges to a nonnegative limit $\ell$ and define a new sequence $(m_n)$ by $m_n=\max\{s_k;k\le n\}$, then $m_n/n$ converges to $\ell$.

The usual epsilon-delta approach works.